# add a value to a dropdownlist populated from database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu

this is my code -

```
 SqlCmd = New SqlCommand("sp_load_names", SqlCnn)
 SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
 SqlDR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
 While SqlDR.Read
      ads_list.Items.Add(New ListItem(SqlDR(1) & ""))
 End While
 SqlDR.Close()
```

this shall populate the dropdownlist data, but in the value i need it to pick up the "ID" field from the stored proc.
the stored proc sends two parameters, ID and Name. so i populate name, but how do i populate the id in value like this -
Mark
Sam
Dennis

i hope im not confusing anyone

Answer (score 0):

One of the ListItem constructor overloads sets both the text and value properties:

`New ListItem("Text", "Value")`

You should be able to access both columns in the SQL data reader using `SqlDR(1)` and `SqlDR(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

ListItems are objects, so you can create your own simple ListItem class to contain both the ID and Display Value

```
Class MyListItem
   Public ID As Integer
   Public Text As String

   Public Sub New(iID As Integer, sText As String)
      Me.ID = iID
      Me.Text = sText
   End Sub

   Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
      Return Me.Text
   End Sub
End Class

...
Dim oItem As MyListItem

While SqlDR.Read
    oItem = new MyListItem(SqlDR(0),SqlDR(1))
    ads_list.Items.Add(oItem)
End While
...

oItem = CType(ads_list.SelectedItem,MyListItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCmd = New SqlCommand("sp_load_names", SqlCnn)
 SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
 SqlDR = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
 While SqlDR.Read
      ads_list.Items.Add(SqlDR(1).ToString)
 End While
 SqlDR.Close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and we thank you for your help. Please do not only post code, a short explanation could be useful.